# Android EditText line numbers

Tags: java, android

I'm making a html IDE and want to add line numbers to an EditText. I tried a think TextView beside the EditText but it has its problems. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

```
private List<String> items = null;
private EditText ideText;
private TextView ln;

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            ideText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ide);
            ln = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lineNumbers);
            // Create Line Numbers
           for(int i=0;i<ideText.getLineCount();i++){
               ln.append(i +"\n");
           }
        }
```

Comment: share something in form of code

Comment: Sounds interesting.....but provide some code...what you've tried

Comment: @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ideText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ide);
        ln = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lineNumbers);
        // Create Line Numbers
       for(int i=0;i<ideText.getLineCount();i++){
        ln.append(i +"\n");
       }
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a custom View that extends EditText.